# Oracle - SELECT with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
NAME                              ID ORIGSSID$
------------------------------ ----- ---------
Reproducibility Renamed 2       1287      1088
Reproducibility Renamed         1284      1088
NoiseDrift                      1049      1049
Reproducibility_8h              1131      1131
Reproducibility                 1088      1088
Noise and Drift                 1263      1049
```

I need to select rows based on two criteria:

1. If `ID` and `ORIGSSID$` are equal and `COUNT(ORIGSSID$) == 1`

OR

2. If there are more than one entry with the same `ORIGSSID$` select one with the biggest `ID`

Expected result in my case is:

```
NAME                              ID ORIGSSID$
------------------------------ ----- ---------
Reproducibility Renamed 2       1287      1088
Reproducibility_8h              1131      1131
Noise and Drift                 1263      1049
```

Please help me to construct SELECT expression..

Comment: I think 1049/1049 should be in the results as well, according to your rules.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, to be more specific 1. If `ID == ORIGSSID$` and `count(ORIGSSID$) == 1`, so 1049/1049 should no meet my criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your two conditions, the logic appears to be:

```
select name, id, ORIGSSID$
from (select t.*,
             max(id) over (partition by ORIGSSID$) as maxid,
             count(*) over (partition by ORIGSSID$) as cnt
      from TABLE.SUBTABLE t
     ) t
where id = ORIGSSID$ or (id = maxid and cnt > 1);
```

According to your sample results, you seem to want:

```
select name, id, ORIGSSID$
from (select t.*,
             max(id) over (partition by ORIGSSID$) as maxid
      from TABLE.SUBTABLE t
     ) t
where id = maxid;
```

Comment: Could you please explain line `from (select t.*`?
My table name (simplified) is `TABLE.SUBTABLE`, if I replace `t` -> `TABLE.SUBTABLE` in your example I receive an error: "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"